# Filtering logs before being ingested by Datadog

Tags: logging, filter, datadog

I am sending logs to datadog from microservices hosted in Kubernetes. Is it possible to filter logs based on the log level - I want to ingest only ERROR logs.

[This doc page](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/logs/advanced_log_collection/?tab=configurationfile#filter-logs) shows some possible filters on the log message, but I want to filter out specific values of log level.

I tried those filters like so

```
ad.datadoghq.com/<container-name>.logs: '[{"source": "REDACTED","service":"REDACTED",
                          "log_processing_rules": 
                    "[{"type": "exclude_at_match","name":"exclude_info","key" : "level","value": "INFO"},
                      {"type": "exclude_at_match","name":"exclude_debug","key" : "level","value": "DEBUG"},
                      {"type": "exclude_at_match","name":"exclude_trace","key" : "level","value": "TRACE"}]"}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than exclude everything else, try to include just the ERROR logs, with something similar to:

```
    ad.datadoghq.com/redacted.logs: >-
      [{
        "source": "redacted",
        "service": "redacted",
        "log_processing_rules": [{
          "type": "include_at_match",
          "name": "ingest_error_logs",
          "pattern" : ".*ERROR.*"
        }]
      }]
```